# SMSManager is Deprecated

Tags: android, sms

i have included this file in a project of android 2.3.3

```
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
```

It shows the code as follows(strikes out the smsmanager text)
import android.telephony.gsm.<strike>SmsManager</strike>;
and a shows message
"SmsManager is deprecated"
how can i fix this?

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, what do you have `android:targetSdkVersion` set to?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) :

> This class is deprecated.
>   Replaced by [android.telephony.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) that supports both GSM and CDMA

Since API 4.

Answer (score 5):

android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager is deprecated  and was replaced by android.telephony.SmsManager that supports both GSM and CDMA.  android.telephony.SmsManager is available for API level 4 and up (a.k.a Android 1.6). See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html). You can use [Android.os.Build.Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to figure out which to use on a given platform

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

just import this one